# read folder path and using the path to access the files and rename it

Tags: vbscript, rename, configuration-files

I want to write a VBScript that can access a config file which has the folder path. Once directed to the folder, there are documents with `_DDMMYYYY`. I want to remove the `_` and the date stamp.

Can somebody help me please?

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Declare the variables to be used from the property file
Dim Folder
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess, obNetwork
Dim strComputer, WshShell, strComputerName

strComputer = "."

Set obNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputerName = obNetwork.ComputerName
Set obNetwork = Nothing

SetConfigFromFile("C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\RenameFile\ConfigPad.txt")
MsgBox "Folder = " & Folder

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run Folder

'---------- Get Variables from ConfigPad.txt ----------
Sub SetConfigFromFile(fileName)
  Dim strConfigLine
  Dim fConFile
  Dim EqualSignPosition
  Dim strLen
  Dim VariableName
  Dim VariableValue

  Set fConFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName)
  While Not fConFile.AtEndOfStream
    strConfigLine = fConFile.ReadLine
    strConfigLine = Trim(strConfigLine)
    'MsgBox(strConfigLine)
    If (InStr(1,strConfigLine,"#",1) <> 1 And Len(strConfigLine) <> 0) Then
      EqualSignPosition = InStr(1, strConfigLine, "=", 1)
      strLen = Len(strConfigLine)
      VariableName = LCase(Trim(MID(strConfigLine, 1, EqualSignPosition-1))) 'line 34
      VariableValue = Trim(Mid(strConfigLine, EqualSignPosition + 1, strLen - EqualSignPosition))
      Select Case VariableName
        'ADD EACH OCCURRENCE OF THE CONFIGURATION FILE VARIABLES(KEYS)
        Case LCase("Folder")
          If VariableValue <> "" Then Folder = VariableValue
      End Select
    End If
  Wend
  fConFile.Close
End Sub

'---------- Rename the documents ----------
Dim FLD
Dim fil
Dim strOldName
Dim strNewName
Dim strFileParts

'Set the folder you want to search.
Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\RenameFile\RenameFile.vbs")

'Loop through each file in the folder
For Each fil in FLD.Files
  'Get complete file name with path
  strOldName = fil.Path

  'Check the file has an underscore in the name
  If InStr(strOldName, "_") > 0 Then
    'Split the file on the underscore so we can get everything before it
    strFileParts = Split(strOldName, "_")
    'Build the new file name with everything before the
    'first under score plus the extension
    strNewName = strFileParts(0) & ".txt"

    'Use the MoveFile method to rename the file
    FSO.MoveFile strOldName, strNewName
  End If
Next

'Cleanup the objects
Set FLD = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

My config file only has this:

```
Folder = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\RenameFile\Test - Copy"
```

Comment: What doesn't work as expected? What do you expect the code to do, and what does it actually do? Are you getting errors? What do they say?

Comment: Line 60, Path not found.

Comment: `C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\RenameFile\RenameFile.vbs` is most likely a file, not a folder. Did you expect `GetFolder` to return the parent folder of that file? That's not how the method works. Use `FSO.GetFile("...").ParentFolder` instead.

Comment: I want to rename documents that are inside the folder path which is stated in the configfile.txt

Comment: Then you need to call `GetFolder` with the variable `Folder` where your other procedure stored that path: `Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(Folder)`.

Comment: It still say as path not found. :/

Comment: Check the value of the variable. Check that the folder actually exists and is a folder. `WScript.Echo Folder & ": " & FSO.FolderExists(Folder)`

Comment: That's weird, it is false but immediately after that it opens the folder that is stated in the config file.

Comment: I don't know how to link the top part with the rename the documents portion. There is something wrong there.

Comment: Do you have redirected folders in your profile? What do you get when you do a `dir "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\RenameFile\Test - Copy"` in a Command Prompt?

Comment: It says that it has 3 Files, 2 Dir.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TS = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\RenameFile\ConfigPad.txt")
SrcFolder = TS.ReadLine
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(SrcFolder)
Set Fls = fldr.files
For Each thing in Fls
    If Left(thing.name, 1) = "_" AND IsNumeric(Mid(thing.name, 2, 8)) Then 
        thing.name = mid(thing.name, 10)
    End If
Next
```

This assumes the first line in the config file is a path. It renames any files starting with an underscore and followed by 8 digits.

Comment: I can't be bothered with you. How dare you say something so pathetic as "it doesn't work". It does because I tested it.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work, why would I lied it work? And I said it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
configfile = "Config File Name Here" 'Example : C:\Documents\Config.txt

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tf = objFSO.OpenTextFile(configfile, 1)

Do Until tf.AtEndOfStream
    cl = tf.ReadLine
    If InStr(cl, "Folder = ") > 0 Then
        Folder = Replace(Replace(cl,"Folder = ",""),chr(34),"")
        tf.Close
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

For Each File in objFSO.GetFolder(Folder).Files
    If InStr(File.Name, "_") > 0 And IsNumeric(Mid(File.Name,InStr(File.Name, "_") + 1,8)) Then
        NewName = Replace(File.Name,Mid(File.Name,InStr(File.Name, "_"),9),"")
        objFSO.MoveFile File.Path, objFSO.GetParentFolderName(File.Path) & "\" & NewName
    End If
Next
MsgBox "Task Complete", vbOKOnly, "Remove Time Stamp"
```